# ArrayList not Initialized

Tags: java, android, arraylist, initialization

I'm trying to import an Array List from one class into another, but Android Studio is saying it's not initialized.  I have my information for the Array List stored in the CourseNameClass so that the information can be shared between the two anonymous classes.  I have the application get the information when one button is clicked and switch to another activity when another is clicked.  How would I work around this?  Here is my code:

```
public class EnterCourseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_course);

    buttonClick();
}

public void buttonClick() {
    final CourseNameClass courseNameShared = new CourseNameClass(" ");

    Button enterAnotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterAnotherButton);
    enterAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);
            String courseNameString = inputText.getText().toString();
            courseNameShared.courseNameInClass = courseNameString;
            inputText.setText("");
        }
    });

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CourseNameClass coursesArrayListInClass;
            Intent i = new Intent(EnterCourseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("course", coursesArrayListInClass);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

class CourseNameClass{
    String courseNameInClass;

    public CourseNameClass(String courseNameInClass){
        this.courseNameInClass = courseNameInClass;
        ArrayList<String> coursesArrayListInClass = new ArrayList<String>();
        coursesArrayListInClass.add(courseNameInClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing an uninitialized object `coursesArrayListInClass` as an "extra" instead of an ArrayList...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void buttonClick() {
    final CourseNameClass courseNameShared = new CourseNameClass(" ");

    Button enterAnotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterAnotherButton);
    enterAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);
            String courseNameString = inputText.getText().toString();
            courseNameShared.courseNameInClass = courseNameString;
            inputText.setText("");
        }
    });

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(EnterCourseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putStringArrayListExtra("course", courseNameShared.getCoursesArrayList());

        startActivity(i);
    }
}


class CourseNameClass {
    String courseNameInClass;

    public CourseNameClass(String courseNameInClass){
        this.courseNameInClass = courseNameInClass;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCoursesArrayList() {
        ArrayList<String> coursesArrayListInClass = new ArrayList<String>();
        coursesArrayListInClass.add(courseNameInClass);
        return coursesArrayListInClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create `ArrayList<String> coursesArrayListInClass` in `CourseNameClass` constructor and then never use it. The `CourseNameClass coursesArrayListInClass;` you create in `OnClick()` metthod is NEW `CourseNameClass` object, and this is an object you did't initialize. But it is not an `ArrayList` object! You used same name for different objects!

To use `ArrayList<String> coursesArrayListInClass` you can for example create new method in `CourseNameClass`:

```
class CourseNameClass{
    String courseNameInClass;
    ArrayList<String> coursesArrayListInClass;

    public CourseNameClass(String courseNameInClass){
        this.courseNameInClass = courseNameInClass;
        coursesArrayListInClass = new ArrayList<String>();
        coursesArrayListInClass.add(courseNameInClass);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
        return coursesArrayListInClass;
    }
}
```